# Cloudwatch monitoring script errors when attempting to send metrics for ASG

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to send use the Cloudwatch monitoring script to send metrics for memory, disk and swap utilization from an EC2 instance to Cloudwatch. In order to run the script I need to provide it AWS credentials or an IAM role. When attempting to use an IAM role I find that I get the below error

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x aws-scripts-mon]$ /home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-
mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --auto-
scaling=only --verbose --aws-iam-role=ACCT-CloudWatch-
service-role
Using AWS credentials file </home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-
mon/awscreds.conf>

WARNING: Failed to call EC2 to obtain Auto Scaling group name. HTTP 
Status Code: 0. Error Message: Failed to obtain credentials for IAM 
role ACCT-CloudWatch-service-role. Available roles: ACCT-service-role

WARNING: The Auto Scaling metrics will not be reported this time.

[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x aws-scripts-mon]$
```

This is what my IAM policy looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [  
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingNotificationTypes",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "autoscaling:DescribePolicies",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ssm:PutParameter",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "ec2:*",
                "kms:*",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLoadBalancerTargetGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

The message states the problem comes from the role it tries to use:

> Failed to obtain credentials for IAM 
>   role ACCT-CloudWatch-service-role. Available roles: ACCT-service-role

Modify this part of your command to `--aws-iam-role=ACCT-
service-role` (I am assuming that this role is the one configured correctly)